# Line spacing in chat using pidgin

Tags: pidgin

I started using pidgin again and I cannot find the option to configure line spacing in chat.  the default appears to be 1.5 lines between messages.  How can I change that?  Or is it another "feature" that all users will love so there is no way to configure it?  Yeah, kinda frustrated with it...

Comment: In part due to this issue, I abandoned Pidgin as worthless and moved to [mcabber](http://mcabber.com/) which suits my needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at this problem as well and suspect that the lines:

```
gtk_text_view_set_pixels_above_lines(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(imhtml), 2);
gtk_text_view_set_pixels_below_lines(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(imhtml), 3);
```

in function `gtk_imhtml_init()` in `pidgin/gtkimhtml.c` are the culprit. So this seems not user modifiable without recompiling the program.

I was able to compile and start pidgin, but I never got that version to read my existing account configuration (and I did not want to install this version before that works). So I was not able to verify whether that actually works. There seem no other relevant places where this, (or `gtk_text_view_get_pixels_inside_wrap()`) is called.

Comment: We don't seem the only ones with this problem [here](http://lifehacker.com/356291/ten-must+have-plug+ins-to-power-up-pidgin) a user Ludovac commented: `.... PSI is better because the font and the vertical line spacing are smaller. With Pidging you spend your time scrolling up and down....`

Comment: This is ... Well, to be honest, what I expected from Pidgin.

Comment: When I have time I might setup a development VM and try to get this to work. I have a few times to often broken tools that have been working. I just don't get it why pidgin doesn't take my existing config and logs into my IM providers when I specify `-c ~/.purple`